# How can I use django to collect and store the pixel locations of mouse clicks on a displayed image?

Tags: django, django-forms, mouseevent

I have a set of images and I'd like to display them to a user and collect the location of mouse clicks on each image. I'd like to do this using django because ultimately I want to integrate these click event data with an existing database that's managed with django.

I know I could do this by coding up my own Python application that displays the image, collects mouse clicks, and stores them in the database. But is there an existing django extension or form that already does this? I'm having trouble getting any useful hits on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i understand you are collecting data from a front-end level. For something like this you should collect the data with Javascript running on your page and have it send an AJAX post to you Django API. That would allow you to store the data easily.

As Django forms operate off of HTTP requests I do not think that there is an extension for doing this in the current Django ecosystem.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. I didn't really understand the distinction between front-end and back-end before.